# Updating values in an object inside an array with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema nested inside another(main) schema. I'd like to increase a Number field in the first schema, however it is an array. So I'd need to access that specific object in that array, and increase a field inside it which is a number. I think what I am looking for is the $inc operator, however I couldn't seem to get it to work.

My schema's:

```
const chainSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  chainName: String,
  streak: Number,
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String,
  pomodoroStreak: Number,
  chains: [chainSchema],
});
```

Post route:

```
app.post("/chainDisplay", function (req, res) {
  const clickedChain = req.body.secret;
  const clickedButton = req.body.submit;

  if (clickedButton === "increase") {
    Chain.findOneAndUpdate(
      { chainName: clickedChain },
      { $inc: { streak: 1 } },
      function (err, foundChain) {
        if (!err) {
          res.redirect("/chain");
        }
      }
    );
  } else if (clickedButton === "decrease") {
    Chain.findOneAndUpdate(
      { chainName: clickedChain },
      { $inc: { streak: -1 } },
      function (err, foundChain) {
        if (!err) {
          res.redirect("/chain");
        }
      }
    );
  }
});
```

I obtain the chainName and trying to use that as a parameter to find that specific object, and increase or decrease the streak by 1. Thank you for your help in advance.

I've tried using the $inc operator alongside mongoose's findOneandUpdate method. I am wondering if I should be updating the User, rather than the Chain itself. I was expecting to increase or decrease the "streak" key by 1 when the relevant button is clicked.

Comment: Your thought is correct, you should be using User, you cannot update subschemas directly, you must use the parent schema.

Comment: Thank you for your response and great information! Now the problem stands as how am I going to use this $inc operator since I am going to find a user. I will find the user by id, then inside the inc operator I go to that user's chains, match it with the chain that is clicked then increase the value by one. I will try some more!